# How to convert Double to String in MongoDB 3.6?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

in aggregation pipeline i need to convert field from `Double` type to `String`. I have `3.6` version of `mongodb`, so i can't use `$toString()` or `convert()` operators.

I've tried operators `$substr` and `$toLower` in the next way:

```
{$project: {"totalScore": {$toLower: "$totalScore"}},
{$project: {"totalScore":  {$substr: [$totalSpent", 0, -1]}]}}}
```

It works, except if number is big it formats output string something like this: "1.55609e+06". And it's not suitable for me. May someone advise any other methods to achieve it? Didn't find another solution.